# Use the comma, or not?

Tags: commas

In a flyer, should the following comma stay — or be omitted?

> Call***,*** or e-mail for more information.

Answer (score 3):

> Call, or e-mail for more information

implies that the reader should "call" or "email for more information". That is to say, to get more information one should email rather than call. For example: call to buy the product; email to get a product info sheet.

> Call or e-mail for more information

implies that either calling or emailing will yield additional information (sounds like what you want).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a comma in this instance, because your list of options is two or less. If you were to add another option, then you would need to use a comma between the first two options.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a comma in a parallel structure of only two elements.  Here's a good explanation:  "A comma is rarely used between just two parallel structures. Only a coordinating conjunction is used between two parallel structures (unless they are independent clauses)."  [De Anza College](http://faculty.deanza.edu/flemingjohn/stories/storyReader$16)